# Free JQuery plugin for drawing UML diagrams

Tags: jquery, uml

Is there a free (for commercial use) jQuery library that I can use to integrate into my website to be able to draw UML diagrams?

Thanks

Comment: To render an UML diagram can be very complicated. Have you checked http://yuml.me/?

Comment: Yes, I've checked that, but it requires users to learn a language to generate a UML. I am looking for a plugin that lets users drag and drop and create class/sequence diagrams.

Answer (score 5):

#### You can try these:

1. jQuery SVG - you would have to create your own UML or Flowchart shapes:  http://keith-wood.name/svg.html
2. Raphael JS - create vector-based graphics using a JavaScript library:  http://raphaeljs.com/
3. JavaScript InfoVis:  http://thejit.org/demos/
4. Commercial (for-pay) tool called mxGraph:  http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html

Comment: None of those work for me. The first 3 require custom coding to implement our own UML solution. 4 works but it's commercial. I am looking for something similar to 4 but that's free.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [jsUML2](http://www.jrromero.net/tools/jsUML2) javascript/HTML5 library. This list of [web-based modeling tools](http://modeling-languages.com/web-based-modeling-tools/) could have also some useful links